# Panasonic Lumix GX80 one point colour

Tags: color, color-management, panasonic-lumix

I am just learning how to use my GX80. I've selected the one point colour setting and tried to select a colour with the touch screen but the photo comes out normal. What setting do I need to change for it to work?thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with star effect with my GX80! Are you taking pictures in RAW only? if so the RAW version will not have this effect. However, if you are combining RAW and jpg then the jpg version should have this. RAW does not capture this detail as this is an in-camera effect.

From the GX80 manual

```
To Set the colour to leave in (one Point Color) 

1. Press Fn1 to display the setting screen. 
2. Select the colour you want to by moving the frame with the arrow keys
    (You can also select the colour you want to leave by touching
      the screen )
3. pressing [DISP] will return the screen to the centre
4. press [MENU/SET] to set.

   **Depending on the subject, the set colour may not be left in.**
```

Comment: I'm in jpeg as far as I know. Haven't changed the settings since buying it. The star effect works on mine. I'm just not sure how to select the specific colour I want for the one point colour. Nothing pops up,  it just takes normal photos..

Comment: @Cambot. I've amended my answer with a extract from the manual. There are two things here that have tripped me up before. 1. Not pressing MENU/SET once the colour has been selected 2. Having too many similar colours in the frame and/or poor light. Otherwise it works fine for me!